# ¿Con qué propositos se agregan class o id a las etiquetas script?

Tags: javascript, html5

He visto que algunas páginas agregan class o id a un script

Ejemplo:

```
<script class="script">
    alert(1)
</script>
```

Porque se realiza esta practica

Captura de pantalla del código fuente de Twitter en donde le asignan un ID a un script

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El utilizo de `class` o `id` como atributo de un tag `script` podrian servir para llamar el fragmento de codigo desde otro lado como prodria ser el caso de un template engine de javascript.

podemos hacer un ejemplo utilizando un template como `Handlebars`

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.12/handlebars.js"></script>

<script class="idioma italiano" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <p>Ciao Fratello, come stai ? </p>
</script>
<script class="idioma castellano" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <p>Hola Hermano, como estas ? </p>
</script>

<script>
  idioma = getUrlParameter("idioma") || "italiano";
  var idiomaTemplate = Handlebars.compile($("script.idioma." + idioma ).html());
  $("body").append(idiomaTemplate())
  
  
function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1),
        sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
        sParameterName,
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

        if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
            return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : decodeURIComponent(sParameterName[1]);
        }
    }
};
  
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.12/handlebars.js"></script>

<script class="idioma italiano" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <p>Ciao Fratello, come stai ? </p>
</script>
<script class="idioma castellano" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <p>Hola Hermano, como estas ? </p>
</script>

<script>
  idioma = getUrlParameter("idioma") || "castellano";
  var idiomaTemplate = Handlebars.compile($("script.idioma." + idioma ).html());
  $("body").append(idiomaTemplate())
  
  
function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1),
        sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
        sParameterName,
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

        if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
            return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : decodeURIComponent(sParameterName[1]);
        }
    }
};
  
</script>
```

en este caso, seria hacer un cambio de idioma en base a la seleccion del usuario, si el usuario quiere ver el contenido en italiano, se llama el fragmento (`script`) en idioma italiano, gracias al utilizo de la clase o del id que le has dado al tag `script`.

espero que te sea de ayuda exitos.

Comment: ahi actualize el codigo sacando los errores presentes e insertando las dos variantes

Answer (score 0):

Las etiquetas de uso para la etiqueta `script` son

1. src: Que sirve para indicar la rurta a un recurso de tipo javascript que ha de invocarse por medio de esta etiqueta
2. type: Que sirve para indicar que tipo va a soportar, en este caso el lenguaje JavaScript
3. charset: el charset usado
4. crossorigin: para indicar como el elemento trata las peticiones de tipo `crossorigin`
5. defer: se usa para indicar que un script se carga hasta que la página ha cargado
6. async: da la capacidad de hacer una descarga asíncrona del archivo js, en cierto punto hacer la interrupción del pintado de la página e interpretar el .js y apenas termine continua con el pintado de la página

Aquí tienes una fuente oficial de la W3C para verificar, los atributos que son necesarios en esta etiqueta [script tag](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/scripting-1.html)

---

```
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
```

**Entonces el uso de `class` para que es?**

> La etiqueta `class` es un atributo de tipo global que se usa para
>   indicar un identificador a mas de un elemento dentro del DOM, con
>   ayuda de CSS sirve para aplicar estilos visuales a 2 o mas elementos a
>   la vez

Entonces si yo hago esto

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <style>
    h1{
      color: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" class="colores">
    document.write("<h1> Hola Mundo </h1>")
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Lo único que estoy generando es aplicarle un color de texto rojo al texto del `h1` que se imprime por medio de la instrucción `document.write`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Uso de ID y CLASS**

1. Los id se utilizan para identificar elementos de manera única y con base en ello poderle aplicar por ejemplo estilos visuales a través del CSS
2. las class solo las debes aplicar cuando identificas que un grupo de elementos: botones, etiquetas, inputs, etc van a necesariamente compartir características y por tanto les vas a aplicar por ejemplo estilos visuales en común a varios de ellos

Comment: Hay más atributos que pueden usarse con la etiqueta `script` que los dos que has puesto.

Comment: si lo  se @AlvaroMontoro he puesto 2 mas y dejé un enlace a la especificación de la w3c para que el OP pueda consultar mas a detalle, espero sea útil

Comment: Después de `src`, las dos más importantes serían las que no comentas: `async` y `defer`. Aparte de los atributos globales.

Comment: ¿Entonces usar class u id es una mala practica?, he editado mi pregunta y añadido una imagen.